# How do I open a browser which Apple gives in popups

Tags: web-browsing

I have seen a type of browser which Apple spits out, for example, when connecting to hotel WiFi's. They seem to be a pop-up window without any specific application.

I find Github's screenshots to be displayed in the same way - [Example](https://hubot.github.com/assets/images/screenshots/dangerroom-full.png). How do I achieve this to open any URL in a similar fashion?

Purpose: This would be a clean way to take screenshots etc.

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish something similar is to use the **Website Popup** workflow in *Automator*.

- Open **Automator**
- Create a new **Workflow** or **Service**
- Add **Get Specified URL's**
- Add **Website Popup**

Modify the settings in each workflow to your preference.  The popup can be then captured for screen shots.

From the [Mac OS X Automation](http://macosxautomation.com/lion/websitepopup/index.html) website:

> #### Website Popup
>
> More and more, services and functionality are moving to the Cloud. Accessing internet-hosted server-based content without
> the hassle and overhead of using a browser can prove to be invaluable
> in providing simple, quick, and elegant workflow soltuions.*[sic]* The
> Website Popup action displays specified HTML or web-based content in a
> floating HUD-like palette that can provide fast access to important
> content and then quicly *[sic]* get out of the way.

Sample using "Website" in a Wikipedia search workflow:

[image: HUD style lookup screenshot]